# How do I properly group the following MySql table without losing data?

Tags: c#, mysql, group-by

I want to group the following table that I want to group by RecordId, but I don't want to lose any data.  Currently, I was grouping by Email which was keeping all the data.

```
    Id  | RecordId | Email            | Message          | ActionId |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     1  | 2        | john@example.com |  Record inserted |  1       |
     1  | 2        | jane@example.com |  Record Updated  |  2       |
     1  | 2        | joe@example.com  |  Record Deleted  |  3       |
```

Doing this query resulted in pretty much the same table:

```
SELECT * FROM Messages
  GROUP BY Email
```

Doing this query results in 1 record which I know why, but I lost the data from the other records, for example, the Email, Message, and ActionId:

```
SELECT * FROM Messages
  GROUP BY RecordId
```

results in

```
    Id  | RecordId | Email            | Message          | ActionId |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     1  | 2        | john@example.com |  Record inserted |  1       |
```

Is there anyway I can `Group By RecordId` and still keep all the data.  I am trying to create one record based on the `RecordId`, while keeping all the data so I can send out an email to all the people in the `Email` Column, but with their respective `Message (Record Inserted, Record Deleted, Record Updated)`.

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: @sgeddes - The result is sort of like the initial table, but I just want to send out `1 email` based on `RecordId `and not `3 emails` based on `Email`.

Answer (score 0):

Will `GROUP_CONCAT()` help?

```
SELECT RecordId, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(",", Email, Message, ActionId) SEPARATOR ";")
FROM Messages GROUP BY RecordId
```

Note: there is a limit of `GROUP_CONCAT()` result length. So if you foresee grouping a lot of records, then its not your solution.

Comment: I had this as an Idea, but i wonder how difficult this will be to parse the data our of the `GROUP_CONCAT` field.  I have a feeling I will exceed the limit,

Comment: shouldn't be difficult. You may `explode()` into array, or apply good regex.

Comment: if you expect the result to be long - then I'm not sure there is a way to group into one line with pure mySQL. Use PHP I think

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with c# well enough, can't help. :(

Answer (score 0):

The bellowing query will return only one record per RecordID with all the information. (It's a bit ugly thought)

```
SELECT  RecordId,

        EMAIL = (   SELECT EMAIL + ';'
                    FROM Messages AS M
                    WHERE Messages.RecordId = M.RecordId
                    FOR XML PATH('')),

        [Message] =(SELECT [Message] + ';'
                    FROM Messages AS M
                    WHERE Messages.RecordId = M.RecordId
                    FOR XML PATH('')),

        ActionId =(SELECT ActionId + ';'
                    FROM Messages AS M
                    WHERE Messages.RecordId = M.RecordId
                    FOR XML PATH(''))

FROM Messages
GROUP BY RecordId
```

Comment: I am getting the error `1 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'XML PATH('')),
        [Message] =(SELECT [Message] + ';'
                  ' at line 6 SQL9.sql 1 1 `

Comment: Sorry, the answer I wrote is in TSQL, probably not supported by MySQL. I should have check that before posting.